# Eclipse without JDT

Tags: eclipse, d, eclipse-jdt, ddt

How can I get Eclipse without JDT or other plugins, so that I can install [D Development Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/d-development-tools) and make an IDE for D only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse Project downloads site ([here for Eclipse 4.5](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/)) contains the smallest builds of Eclipse. The 'Platform Runtime Binary' downloads are probably what you want.